# Show activities in ActionBarSherlock Tab Navigation

Tags: android, tabs, navigation, android-activity

I am developing an app using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html) , using "Tab Navigation"
I have activities which I need to call when user touches any tab. Since I need to use these tabs, so these activities should show the tabs as well. How to achieve the same?

Below is the code snippet:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
private TextView mSelected;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.tab_navigation);
    mSelected = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab tabNW_I = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        tabNW_I.setText("Network Information");
        tabNW_I.setTabListener(this);
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tabNW_I);

        ActionBar.Tab tabNW_T = getSupportActionBar().newTab();            
        tabNW_T.setText("TroubleShoot N/W");
        tabNW_T.setTabListener(this);
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tabNW_T);




}
```

Comment: have a look this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html#actionbar_navigation_tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found Implementing ListView into ActionBarSherlock Fragment Tabs Tutorial, served my purpose.
Here is the link [Fragment tabs](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-listview-into-actionbarsherlock-fragment-tabs-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

By starting a new activity you will be forced to re-populate the tabs on your actionbar. A better plan of action may be to implement your activities as fragments and place them into a ViewPager.
You can then have the tabs control what is showing/selected in the pager. You can also change tabs by reacting to the swipe of the pager.

Here's an example of a viewpager from the Android Developer site:
[How to use a view pager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)